# IS NULL not working in WHERE clause of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have written a Stored procedure in which in given table column named xx can have 0,1 or null. When I give the below condition. SP is ignoring null and returning data only for 0 value.

```
WHERE (CAR_INSPECTION_NEW_TEST.NODAMAGEFLAG is null OR
       CAR_INSPECTION_NEW_TEST.NODAMAGEFLAG = 0) AND
       CAR_INSPECTION_NEW_TEST.ISSUBJECT_TODELIVER = 0
```

Can any one tell what is the problem?

Comment: What does the data look like? Also, does this need to work on both [tag:sql-server] and [tag:mysql]?

Comment: do your missing record have NULLs in their `ISSUBJECT_TODELIVER`column? have you tried `coalesce(CAR_INSPECTION_NEW_TEST.NODAMAGEFLAG, 0)`?

Comment: Condition for NULL seems fine and should work, problem can be identified after checking dataset and complete query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It should work only for sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simple logic it will not return rows where NODAMAGEFLAG is null as long as ISSUBJECT_TODELIVER = 0 is not also valid (because of the AND).

So, check your data please.